# how to create a custom splash page in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, splash-screen

Need to show a popup message in home page only for the first time a user logs into salesforce....

its more like a **splash page**.

it can be a jquery popup as well..

- can i do it using a visualforce page ??? if yes, please give ur suggestions
- can we do it using the sidebar component in salesforce ???

I thought of showing it using a sidebar component by keeping a custom field in user object...everytime he logs in i will check the custom field and the show the popup...since this popup will be shown only for the first time is there anyother better solution instead of querying the user object evertime..

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.open` method of Javascript and for the sidebar provide your scroll option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get fancy to have customized look you can just use jquery modal with some style on document ready.
We can use cookie to store if this is the first time or salesforce user object can tell you this is the first time